# Location of crossdomain.xml Windows Azure

Tags: windows, azure, unity-game-engine

I need to put a crossdomain.xml file in my Windows Azure Web Role. But where ?

I tried to put it in : F:\sitesroot\0

But my Unity3D Web App says : Exception: Unable to connect, as no valid crossdomain policy was found.
I don't know what I am missing. Unity uses by default port (843).

Where to put the crossdomain.xml

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CrossDomainPolicy.xml must be at the root of your application.

If you are using single Web Role just add CrossDomainPolicy.xml at the root of your application and set it up correctly as below:

[image]

Depends on how many "sites" sections you have in your role's ServiceDefinition.csdef , you will get that many \sitesroot\0 and \sitesroot\1 and CrossDomainPolicy.xml will be distributed to all depend on your role solution settings.

Once I discussed this in my following blog:
[Silverlight front end calling to WCF Service, all in one Windows Azure Web Role Sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/11/29/silverlight-front-end-calling-to-wcf-service-all-in-one-windows-azure-web-role-sample.aspx)

Comment: Ok, that's where i put it. For now I have only one section. I will look at your site.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned port 843, which sounds like it would need the Flash protocol, which is a TCP socket listener on port 843 that responds with the cross domain policy when it receives the text `<policy-file-request/>`. Do you need to be doing that? Does your app use sockets?

Avkash's answer is correct for where the XML file should go if you just need to serve it via port 80 from your web app, but if you need to do raw sockets, you'll need to be running something on the server that handles that.